# YOLOv8 crashes when using CUDA - windows 10

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo, torchvision

### I downloaded cuda successfully, and got cudann too

### Proof:

```py
import torch

print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))

logs:
    True
    NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER
```

I am using cuda 12.1. I installed the version of torch with the cuda 12.1 support that I got from the [pytorch site:](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

- `torch==2.1.0+cu121`
- `torchaudio==2.1.0+cu121`
- `torchvision==0.16.0`

I am using this version of ultralytics: `ultralytics==8.0.132`

### The problem:

I tried running this script that Successfully ran before on my cpu:

```py
def main():
    print(torch.cuda.is_available())
    
    box_annotator = sv.BoxAnnotator(
        thickness=2,
        text_thickness=1,
        text_scale=0.35
    )

    id_to_robot_number = {
        1: '1943',
        5: '5990',
        4: '1577',
        3: '1576',
        2: '1690',
        6: '2630'
    }

    trajectories = sdu.setup_trajectories(id_to_robot_number) # Not important to the issue

    model = sdu.setup_model() # The function: return YOLO(r"bumper_weights\v4\best(3).pt")


    source = r'test_videos\dis 1 final 1.mp4'

    for result in model.track(source=source, show=False, stream=True, verbose=False):# CODE CRASH  
        frame = result.orig_img

        ....
```

When the script runs it shows that that I have cuda and then prints out this mess and says that I dont have the `torchvision::nms` function:

```
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\לירן ברט\projects\scouters-dream\main.py", line 112, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\לירן ברט\projects\scouters-dream\main.py", line 33, in main
    for result in model.track(source=source, show=False, stream=True, verbose=False):
  File "C:\Users\לירן ברט\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 35, in generator_context
    response = gen.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\לירן ברט\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\engine\predictor.py", line 252, in stream_inference
    self.results = self.postprocess(preds, im, im0s)
  File "C:\Users\לירן ברט\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\v8\detect\predict.py", line 14, in postprocess
    preds = ops.non_max_suppression(preds,
  File "C:\Users\לירן ברט\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\utils\ops.py", line 253, in non_max_suppression
    i = torchvision.ops.nms(boxes, scores, iou_thres)  # NMS
  File "C:\Users\לירן ברט\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torchvision\ops\boxes.py", line 41, in nms
    return torch.ops.torchvision.nms(boxes, scores, iou_threshold)
  File "C:\Users\לירן ברט\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\_ops.py", line 692, in __call__
    return self._op(*args, **kwargs or {})
NotImplementedError: Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'torchvision::nms' is only available for these backends: [CPU, QuantizedCPU, BackendSelect, Python, FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode, Functionalize, Named, Conjugate, Negative, ZeroTensor, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradXLA, AutogradMPS, AutogradXPU, AutogradHPU, AutogradLazy, AutogradMeta, Tracer, AutocastCPU, AutocastCUDA, FuncTorchBatched, FuncTorchVmapMode, Batched, VmapMode, FuncTorchGradWrapper, PythonTLSSnapshot, FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode, PreDispatch, PythonDispatcher].

CPU: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\vision\vision\pytorch\vision\torchvision\csrc\ops\cpu\nms_kernel.cpp:112 [kernel]
QuantizedCPU: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\vision\vision\pytorch\vision\torchvision\csrc\ops\quantized\cpu\qnms_kernel.cpp:124 [kernel]
BackendSelect: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\BackendSelectFallbackKernel.cpp:3 [backend fallback]
Python: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:153 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\DynamicLayer.cpp:498 [backend fallback]
Functionalize: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\FunctionalizeFallbackKernel.cpp:290 [backend fallback]
Named: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\NamedRegistrations.cpp:7 [backend fallback]
Conjugate: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\ConjugateFallback.cpp:17 [backend fallback]
Negative: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\native\NegateFallback.cpp:19 [backend fallback]
ZeroTensor: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\ZeroTensorFallback.cpp:86 [backend fallback]
ADInplaceOrView: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:86 [backend fallback]
AutogradOther: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:53 [backend fallback]
AutogradCPU: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:57 [backend fallback]
AutogradCUDA: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:65 [backend fallback]
AutogradXLA: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:69 [backend fallback]
AutogradMPS: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:77 [backend fallback]
AutogradXPU: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:61 [backend fallback]
AutogradHPU: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:90 [backend fallback]
AutogradLazy: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:73 [backend fallback]
AutogradMeta: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:81 [backend fallback]
Tracer: registered at ..\torch\csrc\autograd\TraceTypeManual.cpp:296 [backend fallback]
AutocastCPU: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\autocast_mode.cpp:382 [backend fallback]
AutocastCUDA: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\autocast_mode.cpp:249 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchBatched: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\LegacyBatchingRegistrations.cpp:710 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchVmapMode: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:28 [backend fallback]
Batched: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\LegacyBatchingRegistrations.cpp:1075 [backend fallback]
VmapMode: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:33 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchGradWrapper: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\TensorWrapper.cpp:203 [backend fallback]
PythonTLSSnapshot: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:161 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\DynamicLayer.cpp:494 [backend fallback]
PreDispatch: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:165 [backend fallback]
PythonDispatcher: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:157 [backend fallback]
```

### I am gettng this error from this line of code:

```py
for result in model.track(source=source, show=False, stream=True, verbose=False):
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling cuda.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling torch and ultralytics.

I looked up the error online and looked in a couple of forums.. it was also a no go..

Comment: it [seems like](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/3058) the issue may be with the specific torchvision you installed, and the solution might be to uinstall and reinstall torchvision.

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed the issue. I downloaded the version of torchvision required from the pytorch site <https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#:~:text=pip3%20install%20torch%20torchvision%20torchaudio%20%2D%2Dindex%2Durl%20https%3A//download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118>

 and it worked. 

Pip may have-not uninstalled and reinstalled pyvision with cuda support when I ran the command at the first time because I already had torchvision on my computer..